# Generating access token for salesforce rest APIs using restassured

Tags: java, rest, rest-assured, salesforce-lightning

I am trying to generate access token dynamically through rest assured code for Salesforce rest APIs. It is throwing the below error:

```json
{
    "error": "unsupported_grant_type",
    "error_description": "grant type not supported"
}
```

This is the code I am using to generate access token dynamically through rest assured code for Salesforce rest APIs. Below is the code:

```
public static Map<String, String> getAccessToken1() {

    Map<String, String> m_token = new HashMap<String, String>();
    Response response = RestAssured.given()
            .params("username", "*************")
            .params("password", "***********" + "**********")
            .params("client_id", "***********************************************")
            .params("client_secret", "*************************************")
            .params("grant_type", "Implicit")
            .when().log().uri()
            .post("https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token");
    System.out.println(response.getBody().asPrettyString());
    if (response.getStatusCode() == 200) {
        s_token = response.jsonPath().getString("access_token");
        m_token.put("Authorization", "Bearer" + " " + s_token);

    } else {
        Assert.fail(response.jsonPath().getString("error_description"));
    }
    return m_token;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `"grant_type", "Implicit"` ? Have you tried with postman? I don't think it's RA problem.